# Npm Error when install vue.js 2 using webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, vuejs2, npm-install, vue-cli

I have error when I install veu using vue cli.
I use "vue init webpack-simple frontend".
I use node.js '9.9 and npm '5.6.0.

[this Screenshot about error.](https://ibb.co/gC2NJz) ~ I'm Sorry I don't use imgur.com to upload image, because the website is maintenance.

Comment: Try "npm cache clean --force" first and remove node_modules before next run. If it doesn't work then please publish your npm version here

Comment: Sorry, it's doesn't work. I use node js v.9.9.0 and npm v.5.6.0

Comment: Could you share the output of the debug log?